# Implementing Custom JsonWriter (JSON.net)

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have been working on implementing this a custom JSON writer by following [this sample](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonWriter.htm)

I'm overriding the `WriteValue` methods so that instead of printing the value of a json, I print the `Type.ToString()` and conceal the real value of the item.

I'm having trouble with this method:

```
private void WriteValueElement(string elementName, JTokenType type)
{
    _writer.WriteStartElement(elementName);
    _writer.WriteAttributeString("type", type.ToString());
}
```

And particularly with this statement `_writer.WriteStartElement(elementName);`

I just can't figure out where this WriteStartElement is. This method signature doesn't exist in the [baseClass](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/0238b51162c24caeaf87ac3152d648d130961f49/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonWriter.cs), but also nothing in the sample

Comment: In the sample you linked, `_writer` is an [`XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlWriter(v=vs.110).aspx) (see line 3 of the sample).  [`WriteStartElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8t5yhhk(v=vs.110).aspx) writes the opening tag for the XML element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this by subclassing [`JsonTextWriter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextWriter.cs) or [`JsonWriter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonWriter.cs), you're going to need to override all the [`WriteValue`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) methods and remap the value being written.  There are many methods with this name, and since Newtonsoft could in theory add new methods in later versions (for `BigNumber`, for instance) this could become a maintenance nuisance.

A simpler solution might be to [serialize to `JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) then remap the values like so:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IList<JToken> ChildrenTokenList(this JContainer container)
    {
        return container;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<JToken> DescendantsAndSelf(this JToken node)
    {
        // Small wrapper adding this method to all JToken types.
        if (node == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<JToken>();
        var container = node as JContainer;
        if (container != null)
            return container.DescendantsAndSelf();
        else
            return new[] { node };
    }

    public static JToken MapValues(this JToken root, Func<JValue, JValue> map)
    {
        if (map == null || root == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (root is JValue)
            return map((JValue)root);
        else
        {
            root = root.DeepClone();
            foreach (var container in root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JContainer>())
            {
                var children = container.ChildrenTokenList();
                for (int i = 0, n = children.Count; i < n; i++)
                    if (children[i] is JValue)
                        children[i] = map((JValue)children[i]);
            }
            return root;
        }
    }

    public static JToken MapValuesToValueTypes(this JToken root)
    {
        return root.MapValues(v => (v.Type == JTokenType.Null ? (JValue)null : (JValue)v.Type.ToString()));
    }
}
```

If you insist on subclassing the writer, a prototype implementation would look like:

```
public class ValueTypeJsonWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    public ValueTypeJsonWriter(TextWriter textWriter)
        : base(textWriter)
    {
    }

    private void WriteValueType(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            base.WriteNull();
        else
        {
            var token = JToken.FromObject(value);
            base.WriteValue(token.Type.ToString());
        }
    }

    public override void WriteValue(object value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(bool value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(bool? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(byte value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(byte? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(byte[] value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(char value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(char? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(DateTime value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(DateTime? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(DateTimeOffset value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(DateTimeOffset? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(decimal value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(decimal? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(double value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(double? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(float value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(float? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(Guid value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(Guid? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(int value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(int? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(long value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(long? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(sbyte value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(sbyte? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(short value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(short? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(string value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(TimeSpan value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(TimeSpan? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(uint value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(uint? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(ulong value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(ulong? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(Uri value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(ushort value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }

    public override void WriteValue(ushort? value)
    {
        WriteValueType(value);
    }
}
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MWz8sX).

Comment: I will attempt to remap the values before subclassing and report back. Thanks for the help!