# Create invalid Json with Newtonsoft - Allow invalid objects?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, esi

I'm deliberately trying to create invalid JSON with Newtonsoft Json, in order to place an ESI include tag, which will fetch two more json nodes.

This is my JsonConverter's WriteJson method:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    mApiResponseClass objectFromApi = (mApiResponseClass)value;

    foreach (var obj in objectFromApi.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (obj.Name == "EsiObj")
        {
            writer.WriteRawValue(objectFromApi.EsiObj);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(obj.Name);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj.GetValue(value, null));
        }
    }
}
```

The EsiObj in mApiResponseClass is just a string, but it needs to be written into the JSON response to be interpretted without any property name - so that hte ESI can work.

This of course results in an exception with the Json Writer, with value:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriterException: 'Token Undefined in state Object
>   would result in an invalid JSON object. Path ''.'

Is there any way around this?

An ideal output from this would be JSON formatted, technically not valid, and would look like this:

```
{
value:7,
string1:"woohoo",
<esi:include src="/something" />
Song:["I am a small API","all i do is run","but from who?","nobody knows"]
}
```

**Edit:**
Using ESI allows us to have varying cache lengths of a single response - i.e. we can place data that can be cached for a very long time in some parts of the JSON, and only fetch updated parts, such as those that rely on client-specific data.
ESI is not HTML specific. (As some state below) It's being run via Varnish, which supports these tags.
Unfortunately, it's required that we do only put out 1 file as a response, and require no further request from the Client.
We cannot alter our response either - so i can't just add a JSON node specifically to contain the other nodes.

**Edit 2:** The "more json nodes" part is solved by ESI making a further request to our backend for user/client specific data, i.e. to another endpoint. The expected result is that we then merge the original JSON document and the later requested one together seamlessly. (This way, the original document can be old, and client-specific can be new)

**Edit 3:**
The endpoint /something would output JSON-like fragments like:

```
teapots:[ {Id: 1, WaterLevel: 100, Temperature: 74, ShortAndStout: true}, {Id: 2, WaterLevel: 47, Temperature: 32, ShortAndStout: true} ],
```

For a total response of:

```
{
value:7,
string1:"woohoo",
teapots:[ {Id: 1, WaterLevel: 100, Temperature: 74, ShortAndStout: true}, {Id: 2, WaterLevel: 47, Temperature: 32, ShortAndStout: true} ],
Song:["I am a small API","all i do is run","but from who?","nobody knows"]
}
```

Comment: can you give us an example of the expected output please, so it's entirely clear?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).    This is counterintuitive to what JSON is.  Why not add it as a property of the JSON object - does it need to be an invalid JSON object.  Please clarify your intent on what you are trying to achieve and why.

Comment: You can't expect a JSON library to write invalid JSON. So Newtonsoft is the wrong choice for a start. Kami is write your likely looking at this the wrong way. If you really , really need to do this then your going to have to write your own `StringWriter` implementation that turns your object into this format yourself, likely using reflection, etc. I don't know ESI but it seems to be a HTML caching technology. I don't really see what this has to do with JSON at all?

Comment: Agree with the other comments above, it's hard to believe this is the best solution to your problem. You say the include tag "will fetch two more json nodes"...when, and how, is this happening exactly? What are you really trying to achieve? ESI appears to be intended to work with HTML, not JSON

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far - perhaps this is an XY problem example too. In that case - we need to cache a chunk of JSON in varnish cache, and blend in a second requests JSON in a specific point, leading to 1 document with parts made up of different ages. The intention is to cut our API load massively.

Comment: You can use `JsonWriter.WriteRawValue()` to write invalid JSON to the output stream, see e.g. [How can I serialize and deserialize a type with a string member that contains “raw” JSON, without escaping the JSON in the process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40529125/3744182) or [How to deserialize dodgy JSON (with improperly quoted strings, and missing brackets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46797460/3744182).

Comment: Alternatively, if your file format is well-defined, similar to JSON, but not actually JSON, you could subclass `JsonWriter` and implement your own output format.  See e.g. [Implementing Custom JsonWriter (JSON.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32612392) or https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonWriter.htm

Comment: Our format is not well defined... yet. Still a few decisions to make. But we could subclass JsonWriter. hmm.
Can't use WriteRawValue() sadly - as that does then complain about invalid format in the end.
Testing using Middleware in the pipeline now to replace a Json Object instead - that way we can output valid json and do a very quick tag replacement to add the ESI payload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your basic problem is that a [`JsonWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter.htm) is a state machine, tracking the current [JSON state](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_SetWriteState.htm) and validating transitions from state to state, thereby ensuring that badly structured JSON is not written.  This is is tripping you up in two separate ways.

**Firstly**, your `WriteJson()` method is not calling [`WriteStartObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteStartObject.htm) and [`WriteEndObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteEndObject.htm).  These are the methods that write the `{` and `}` around a JSON object.  Since your "ideal output" shows these braces, you should add calls to these methods at the beginning and end of your `WriteJson()`.

**Secondly**, you are calling `WriteRawValue()` at a point where well-formed JSON would not allow a value to occur, specifically where a property name is expected instead.  It is expected that this would cause an exception, since the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteRawValue.htm) states:

> Writes raw JSON where a value is expected and updates the writer's state.

What you can instead use is `WriteRaw()` which is [documented](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteRaw.htm) as follows:

> Writes raw JSON without changing the writer's state.

However, `WriteRaw()` won't do you any favors.  In specific, you will need to take care of writing any delimiters and indentation yourself.

**The fix** would be to modify your converter to look something like:

```
public class EsiObjConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    const string EsiObjName = "EsiObj";

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType()) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Non-object type {0}", value));
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        int propertyCount = 0;
        bool lastWasEsiProperty = false;
        foreach (var property in contract.Properties.Where(p => p.Readable && !p.Ignored))
        {
            if (property.UnderlyingName == EsiObjName && property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                var esiValue = (string)property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(esiValue))
                {
                    if (propertyCount > 0)
                    {
                        WriteValueDelimiter(writer);
                    }
                    writer.WriteWhitespace("\n");
                    writer.WriteRaw(esiValue);
                    // If it makes replacement easier, you could force the ESI string to be on its own line by calling
                    // writer.WriteWhitespace("\n");

                    propertyCount++;
                    lastWasEsiProperty = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var propertyValue = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value);

                // Here you might check NullValueHandling, ShouldSerialize(), ...

                if (propertyCount == 1 && lastWasEsiProperty)
                {
                    WriteValueDelimiter(writer);
                }
                writer.WritePropertyName(property.PropertyName);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, propertyValue);

                propertyCount++;
                lastWasEsiProperty = false;
            }
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    static void WriteValueDelimiter(JsonWriter writer)
    {
        var args = new object[0];
        // protected virtual void WriteValueDelimiter() 
        // https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteValueDelimiter.htm
        // Since this is overridable by client code it is unlikely to be removed.
        writer.GetType().GetMethod("WriteValueDelimiter", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(writer, args);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the serialized output would be:

```
{
  "value": 7,
  "string1": "woohoo",
<esi:include src="/something" />,
  "Song": [
    "I am a small API",
    "all i do is run",
    "but from who?",
    "nobody knows"
  ]
}
```

Now, in your question, your desired JSON output shows JSON property names that are not properly quoted.  If you really need this and it is not just a typo in the question, you can accomplish this by setting [`JsonTextWriter.QuoteName`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_QuoteName.htm) to `false` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7555096) to *[Json.Net - Serialize property name without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7553516/10263)* by [Christophe Geers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893099/christophe-geers):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new EsiObjConverter<mApiResponseClass>() },
};    
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
{
    writer.QuoteName = false;
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writer.Indentation = 0;
    JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Serialize(writer, obj);
}
```

Which results in:

```
{
value: 7,
string1: "woohoo",
<esi:include src="/something" />,
Song: [
"I am a small API",
"all i do is run",
"but from who?",
"nobody knows"
]
}
```

This is *almost* what is shown in your question, but not quite.  It includes a comma delimiter between the ESI string and the next property, but in your question there is no delimiter:

```
<esi:include src="/something" /> Song: [ ... ]
```

Getting rid of the delimiter turns out to be problematic to implement because [`JsonTextWriter.WritePropertyName()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_WritePropertyName.htm) automatically writes a delimiter when not at the beginning of an object.  I think, however, that this should be acceptable.  ESI itself will not know whether it is replacing the first, last or middle property of an object, so it seems best to not include the delimiter in the replacement string at all.

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NoOhhO).

Comment: That is one hell of an answer. The quote's are missing because it was written in a hurry - not a requirement. But thanks for noticing it!
I will give this a whirl in the morning and see if we can do this over the Middleware pipeline i mentioned in the comment above - then we can test out performance of both. I wonder though - would this limit us to a very Newtonsoft specific serialisation? Or is this something generally supported by multiple serialisers? (I can research that one my own - but if you have input, i have eyes!)

Comment: This answer is entirely Newtonsoft-specific.  There's no standard way to write badly-formed JSON that will work with multiple serializers.

Comment: With a few tweaks to our JSON object to merge in, this worked beautifully. Thanks!